# Django and Ajax, submitting form does not create new object

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm trying to create a new 'Sounds' object using the following ajax:

```
var data = new FormData();
            data.append('title', 'test_1');
            data.append('numobj', '{{instance.numobj}}');
            data.append('sound', blob);

$.ajax({
                url: "{% url 'posts:post_create' %}",
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,   
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    alert('success');
                }
            });
```

There are 3 field in the form:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
        model = Sounds

        fields = [
        'title',
        'numobj',
        'sound',
        ]
```

And here's the view that submits the form:

```
def post_create(request):
    form= PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)


    if form.is_valid():

        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    context= {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'post_form.html',context,)
```

Whenever I submit the ajax, it gives me the success alert, but no new object is created. I'm thinking this may be due to the way the fields are appended to the FormData instance. Problem is, I'm not getting any errors to debug with. Any clues?

Comment: Success alert does not mean your form was valid, ajax request is still successful even if form was not valid. In the view check if  `form.is_valid()` becomes True if not `print form.errors` to see what are errors. P.S you can't redirect in ajax request and try to return JSON response.

Comment: Your view seems to return a HTTP 200 OK status whether the post was successful or not. You should return some 4xx error response and an error message if the form validation failed.